# Parse Raw String date to actual Datetime object

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I have a date string as "9 July 1pm CET" I want to convert that to proper datetime object with my system timezone that is IST.

How can i parse it to proper datetime object?

Comment: Hi. Please edit your question to show what you tried already. Also, is it just this string, or is this just an example? Are all inputs in CET? If so, which specific location do you mean? Most (but not all) places that use CET use CEST during the summer. Also, which location do you mean for the output? (The I in IST can stand for Isreal, India, or Ireland.). Or do you just want it in the  system local time zone, whatever it happens to be?

Comment: Hello. @MattJohnson-Pint I have tried using DateTime.Parse(date) however I am not getting proper date as my string doesnt have year in it. I want to parse it to system local timezone and year needs to be considered as the current year.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] dateStrings = {"2008-05-01T07:34:42-5:00", 
                              "2008-05-01 7:34:42Z", 
                              "Thu, 01 May 2008 07:34:42 GMT"};
      foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
      {
         DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
         Console.WriteLine($"Converted {dateString} to {convertedDate.Kind} time {convertedDate}");
      }                              
   }
}
```